# Как добавить названия осей в vue-chartjs?

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить подписи - названия осей X и Y в компоненте 'vue-chartjs'? Или м.б. посоветуйте другой компонент для Vue, который легче кастомизируется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться scaleLabel

```
options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
       {
         scaleLabel: {
           display: true,
           labelString: 'Ось Y'
         },
       }
      ],
      xAxes: [
       {
         scaleLabel: {
           display: true,
           labelString: 'Ось X'
         },
       }
      ],
    }
  }
```

Документация: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#scale-title-configuration